# Tab vs Space indenting (Dreamweaver vs NetBeans) problem

Tags: netbeans, tabs, dreamweaver, indentation, space

I use Dreamweaver at work and NetBeans IDE at home, but in both cases project is stored at github. My problem is that NetBeans seems to be constructing code indenting out of spaces and when opened in dreamweaver or exported to github, indenting here and there breaks (moves unexpectedly further then it was intended or vice versa), although when opened again in NetBeans, goes back to normal. It has been pain for some time already. Is there any resolution to this?

I should say that we at work (and me including) prefer tab indenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the IDE's definition of a TAB. There are usually options within the IDE to indent using a TAB but turn the TAB into a given number of SPACES. I usually indent using TAB but have the IDE turn that into 3 SPACES. This means that it doesn't matter what I (or anyone else) use to read my code later the indets are always the same.
In NetBeans you need to look in the Code Editor options but I have no idea where to find the settings in Dreamweaver.

Comment: For the indent tab/space settings in Dreamweaver: Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences -> Code Format

Answer (score -1):

**Its been known that one should use double space rather than tab, because that fact that different IDEs define how the tab button works DIFFERENTLY.**

For example, emberjs team require contributor to use double-space rather than tab for formatting the code.

It make sense that to use something recognized in common without an IDE, so that the code structure will not be a problem in a highly collaborated coding team environment.

**HOWEVER**, if customization of how a tab works in an IDE is enabled, tab will be a great time saver in this case-- Press twice the button cost 200% of the time to press one obviously :)

Hope that helps!